# I want to merge data from multiple excel workbooks in a folder into single excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have to pick single row (row 9) data (out of 5 rows (row 6-10) of data in each file) from multiple excel files. all these files are in single folder and the consolidation file is one level up in file structure. Below given code copies 4 (row 6-9) rows. Please help:

Code being used is given below:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    'MsgBox "Welcome to ANALYSIS TABS"
    'End Sub

    'Sub simpleXlsMerger()
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object

    MsgBox "Welcome to Merging Platform..."

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'change folder path of excel files here
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\00508069\Desktop\New folder\data")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj
    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

    'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
    'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
    'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
    'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point

    Range("A9:IV" & Range("A10").End(xlUp).Row).Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

    'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial


    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    bookList.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
Range("A9:IV" & Range("A10").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
```

more strictly in this part

```
Range("A10").End(xlUp).Row
```

which says "From cell A10 go up to the cell where block of data ends and take row number of this cell". In your case it means 6.

Use this instead and you'll be fine

```
Range("A9:IV9").Copy
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip buddy. small issue .. first cell of the 9th row to be copied is a reference to a cell in 6th row. Instead of copying the value for first cell of 9th row it indicates #REF error in the copied sheet.  can you also suggest a way around for same.

Comment: At the end of line `Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial` add `xlPasteValues`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]